# Choosing layers to be trained and adding skip connections in the trained Inception model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I want to train a model with CT Grayscale images such as this one:

[image]

For certain classes of diseases my training set is limited , e.g 2,000 positives with 98,000 negatives.

I am thinking to use transfer learning to avoid overfitting and boost the effectiveness of my model but I also realize that I should fine tune the model since the kind of images I am feeding the model are very different from the kind of images with which the Inception model I will use has been trained.

My problem then is that I am not sure how many layers I should keep fixed and how many trainable.

I am thinking then to use skip connections to apply a stochastic depth letting the network to learn how many layers trully needs.

So I am thinking to implement the following architecture.

[image]

I.e. I will add skip connections between the layers of the pretrained inception model that comes with Keras (Tensorflow 2.0).

I would welcome advice on how to implement these ideas.  In particular how to split the network into three parts, leave the first part untouched (untrainable) and train the second part after adding the skip connections.  The implementation should be in Keras.

Comment: Here is some advice that will be helpful. It is as much for readers considering helping as it is for you. (1) you are probably asking too many questions. Eight posts in two days means that you are not waiting for answers on one thing before jumping to the next thing. This would further indicate to me that you are not doing the necessary research. (2) You are adding chatty material about appreciating help, even though many editors have removed this from your prior posts. Technical writing is an expectation here. Meta references are available on request.

Answer (score 1):

1. Transfer learning is indeed the right approach. This allows you to make use of the trained weights to take care of the 'generic' tasks of DL image processing, such as shape recognition, edge detection, etc, and, in a manner of speaking, conserve your data (input and labels) for retooling the existing the neural network for your specific task.
2. As a rule of thumb, the closer the weights are to the input, the more generic their function and the less you want to retrain them. Conversely, the closer the weights are to the output, the more task specific is their function and the more retraining they require.
3. I suggest training the endpoint classifier before retraining existing weights. 1-2 fully connected layers (read: `Dense`) with your favorite activation function + 1 fully connected layer with the `softmax` activation (as we want the output to be the predicted probability of each disease) should probably do the trick. When training this (the endpoint classifier) be sure to freeze all other layers (or use bottleneck features - see how in the link below).
4. Only then you should retrain existing weights - this is called fine-tuning. I suggest unfreezing the first inception [module](https://maelfabien.github.io/deeplearning/inception/#what-is-an-inception-module)*, then allowing it (and the already trained endpoint classifier from the last step!) to retrain. then maybe unfreeze the next inception module, and allow it to train as well (again, while also allowing the first inception module and the new endpoint classifier to retrain as well. When retraining a segment, always allow the weights downstream to retrain as well).
5. Be advised that fine-tuning should use a slow training rate.
6. To the best of my understanding skip connections DO NOT "let the network to learn how many layers truly needs.". They mostly allow the circumvention of the diminishing gradient problem. The "skipped" layers do not become "optional", they will participate in generating the output. And, since the weights used do not account for inputs that will be added via skip connections, I believe it will render the training of the weights irrelevant, requiring the retraining of the entire network and thus preventing transfer learning.

   It would be an interesting experiment, but try it at your own peril.
7. If you really want skip connections, I suggest you make use of a model that already has them (and whose weights are therefore adjusted to it), such as ResNet.

Please view this link for more ideas regarding the utilization of transfer learning, bottle neck features, and fine tuning. And augmentation, while your at it.

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

*By that I mean first one from the prescriptive of the output, that is, the one highest in your image.